# Nested itemize with large lines in ConTeXt

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, itemize

When I try to nest lists like this:

```
\starttext
\startitemize[n]
  \item bla
  \item \startitemize[a]
    \item bla $\displaystyle\int$
    \item bla
  \stopitemize
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

I get this result, where the *2* and the *a* are not aligned:

[image: Misaligned items]

This problem is caused by the large line `$\displaystyle\int$`.

I can somewhat work around this using some `\vskip` manually, but this is far from ideal.

The equivalent code in LaTeX works well.

I use ConText MkIV (2013.05.28) from the standalone installation.

Comment: `\smash{$\displaystyle\int$}`?

Comment: `\smash{...}` doesn't really work because the integral symbol will overwrite the text on the lines above and below.

Comment: See http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=53347783.2060600%40wxs.nl

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been fixed in the latest beta ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpYTP.png)).